# Повернуть робота e-puck в webots на заданный угол

Tags: python

Задача повернуть робота e-puck в webots на заданный угол, не засекая время движения робота и не проверяя каждый момент, что робот повернулся на нужный угол. Колеса принимают значения в радианах, заданный угол в градусах.
Результат: робот поворачивается на 35.036 градусов. Я не понимаю, почему работает неправильно.

```
D = 52 # Длина оси
R = 20.5 # Радиус колеса

angle = 45
angleWheels = 2*math.pi*(angle * D) / (2*R * 360)
left_motor.setPosition(angleWheels)
right_motor.setPosition(-angleWheels)
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А точка вращения находится в центре оси? Или подпорка влияет (там же должна быть третья точка опоры) ? По картинке этого епука не очень понятно.

Comment: Да, вращается относительно своего центра.